# Consume an event of Alfresco in my Java application

Tags: java, web-services, alfresco, alfresco-share

I have a requirement where i want to capture an event which occurred in Alfresco in my java application . for e.g i select a particular folder from my Alfresco repository , i need to information of which folder i selected in my java application . Kindly help

Answer (score 1):

You have the possibility to write a Java Behaviour that is triggered for some nodespecific events in the alfresco repository. For example if a node is created, a property is updated, an association is created etc. See
http://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/Services_Framework#Component_Policies

When the event is triggered you could write some code that notifies your application to do what you want.

Comment: What do i use to notify my java application about the occurred event ?

Comment: What type of application are we talking about? You could have some kind of messaging service, you could notify a REST-service or something similar. That depends on the architecture of your application.

Comment: I have created a rest webservice in java , i need to call the webservice from alfresco share page on the click of a button , how can i achieve it ?

Comment: On click of a button? Could you be a little more specific on the use case you have? What events do you need to capure in Alfresco?

Comment: I have an integration with Alfresco such that, i select a folder in Alfresco share and on the click of the button , i send the folderid of the folder selected back to my java application for uploading the document.